# Kendo grid resizable column width

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

The grid columns may be resizable. I want to store user-adjusted columns width and restore them when the next session starts.

The best way to store columns width I've found is the following:

```
var element = $('#grid').kendoGrid({
   ...
    resizable: true,
    columnResize: function(e) {
        var state = {};
        this.columns.every(function(c,i) {
            state[c.field] = c.width;
            return true;
        });
        var state_txt = JSON.stringify(state);
        localStorage['profile_userprofile_grid_column_width'] = state_txt;
    }
}
```

Now I want to restore column width saved in the previous user session. I can read columns width from the storage:

```
var state = JSON.parse(localStorage['profile_userprofile_grid_column_width']);
```

Does somebody know some elegant way to apply these values back to the grid if it is already created at this time? The resize handle does it internally, so it is possible, but the code doing it in the grid source is ugly.

Comment: Did you find a solution to your question?

Answer (score 0):

You can trigger the `columnResize` event post initilisation as shown below

```
function grid_columnResize(e) {
  // Put your code in here
  console.log(e.column.field, e.newWidth, e.oldWidth);
}
$("#grid").kendoGrid({
  columns: [
    { field: "name" },
    { field: "age" }
  ],
  dataSource: [
    { name: "Jane Doe", age: 30 },
    { name: "John Doe", age: 33 }
  ],
  resizable: true
});
var grid = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid");
grid.bind("columnResize", grid_columnResize);
```

[Documentation](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/web/grid#events-columnResize)

Comment: Your code doesn't trigger columnResize event, but binds columnResize event handler instead. Anyway, triggering the event doesn't help, probably because the event itself is generating by the resize handle **after** it really resized the column.

The code below triggers the event, but it doesn't help:

    g = $('#grid')
    gg = g.getKendoGrid()
    gg.trigger('columnResize',{column:gg.columns[1],oldWidth:gg.columns[1].width,newWidth:400,sender:gg})

(don't know, why the code is not formatting as described in the help)

Comment: My mistake I should have said `bind` instead of `trigger`. What do you mean by "it doesn't help"? Does the code do anything at all?

Comment: I mean that my code triggering columnResize event manually doesn't lead to resizing the column on the screen, although leads to calling event handlers for the columnResize event.

I want to make restoring columns width, i.e. - store it to the local storage on columnResize event (the code from the original post does it), and when the next session starts, read it from the local storage back and pass it to the grid, so the grid would have the same columns width as in the session before.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question, but here is what we have. Function handles column widths and groups.

```
var _updateResultsGridColumns = function(columns, groups) {
    var kendoGrid = $resultsGrid.data("kendoGrid");
    if (kendoGrid) {
        kendoGrid.setOptions({
            columns: columns,
        });

        var dataSource = kendoGrid.dataSource;
        dataSource.group(groups);
        kendoGrid.setDataSource(dataSource);
    }
}
```