# How can I use Jasmine to test Kendo UI grid column resize event

Tags: angularjs, kendo-ui

Does anyone know how I can test kendo grid's column resizing?

The grid is built using an angularjs directive called sgGrid. It uses data taken from a javascript object called accountColumns on the scope where I set an initial column width of 100px.

I then want to trigger the 'columnResize' event on the grid.

Next I get get the column's width again and expect it to have changed because the columnResize event has been triggered.

```
 it('should resize the column when column resize event is fired', function () {
    angular.mock.inject(function($compile, $rootScope, $timeout) {
        var scope = $rootScope.$new();

        // javascript object containing data for columns used in the directive to construct the grid
        scope.accountColumns = [
            {field: 'accountId', title: 'AccountId', dataType: 'integer', width: '100px'},
            ...more fields here
        ];

         var elem = $compile('<div sg-grid sg-columns="accountColumns"></div>')(scope); // construct the grid. sg-grid is an angularjs directive that creates a kendo grid

        $rootScope.$apply();
        $httpBackend.flush();

        var grid = elem.find('div[data-role="grid"]').data('kendoGrid'); // the kendo grid object

        $timeout.flush(100); // wait for DOM to load

        var colWidth = elem.find('colgroup col').eq(0).css('width'); // get the 1st column, AccountId

        expect(colWidth).toBe('100px'); // expect col width to be 100px because this is what we specified in the json

        grid.trigger(columnResize);

        colWidth = elem.find('colgroup col').eq(0).css('width'); // get the 1st column, AccountId

        expect(colWidth).toBe('200px'); // 200px just an arbitrary figure, the point is I expect the width to have changed

    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks to @nnseva for the answer which I found here: [Kendo grid resizable column width](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20379967/kendo-grid-resizable-column-width)

First, you must bind the event to the grid, passing in a handler function

Next, you trigger the event, passing a javascript object that contains the new width and grid

Finally, in the handler function, you update the width of the relevant with value taken from the javascript object:

```
it('should resize the column when column resize event is fired', function () {
   angular.mock.inject(function($compile, $rootScope, $timeout) {
      var scope = $rootScope.$new();

      function gridColumnResizeHandler(e) {
         e.sender.columns[0].width=e.newWidth; // update the column's width
      }

      // javascript object containing data for columns used in the directive to construct the grid
      scope.accountColumns = [
         {field: 'accountId', title: 'AccountId', dataType: 'integer', width: '100px'},
        ...more fields here
      ];

      var elem = $compile('<div sg-grid sg-columns="accountColumns"></div>')(scope); // construct the grid. sg-grid is an angularjs directive that creates a kendo grid

      $rootScope.$apply();
      $httpBackend.flush();

      var grid = elem.find('div[data-role="grid"]').data('kendoGrid'); // the kendo grid object

      $timeout.flush(100); // wait for DOM to load

      var colWidth = elem.find('colgroup col').eq(0).css('width'); // get the 1st column, AccountId

      expect(colWidth).toBe('100px'); // expect col width to be 100px because this is what we specified in the json

      grid.bind("columnResize", gridColumnResizeHandler); // bind the event

      grid.trigger('columnResize',{column:grid.columns[1], oldWidth:100, newWidth:200, sender:grid}); // trigger the event, passing in a js object with relevant data

      colWidth = elem.find('colgroup col').eq(0).css('width'); // get the 1st column, AccountId

      expect(colWidth).toBe('200px'); // now because of the handler function you can be assured the column will have been increased.

});
```

});